# Spring Boot, Velocity Tools

Tags: spring, velocity, spring-boot

I'm trying to integrate spring boot with velocity tools but it still fails, the documentation did not find anything related to how to load velocity.properties, anyone have any help? Thank you.

Comment: Please add information about your current configuration.

Comment: ...as well as information about how exactly it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some Boot/Velocity configuration issues this morning. You are right that the documentation is spare here.

If you are looking to use Velocity for Spring MVC templating, be sure to include `spring-context-support` on the classpath. Based on the behavior, it appears that Boot is doing some classpath autodetection here, and creates `VelocityConfigurer` and `VelocityViewResolver` beans if and only if `spring-context-support` is on the classpath.